# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for '' with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have these Schemas in my FastAPI application:

```
class Run(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(..., description="Run id")
    type: str = Field(..., description="Type")


class RunsResponse(BaseModel):
    data: list[Run] = Field(..., description="List of existing runs")
    links: dict = Field(..., description="link to runs")
```

Then I have this decorator to use for all the endpoints:

```
def handle_request(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (requests.exceptions.SSLError, requests.exceptions.RequestException) as ex:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=str(ex))

        return response

    return wrapper
```

And this route:

```
@router.get(
    "/runs",
    response_model=RunsResponse,
)
@handle_request
async def get_runs(request: Request) -> JSONResponse:
    response = send_request(request, SOME_URL)

    return JSONResponse(content=response)
```

So if I try the api without having those codes in a decorator, everything works fine. But when I put the codes in a decorator and use it on my router function, I get this error:

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for RunsResponse
>
> response
>
> value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

I can't debug the code cause the error happens right after I press the *Execute* button in Swagger. I suspect it has something to do with `@wraps` from `functools` but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can anyone help me with this please?

**UPDATE:**

I'm adding the `send_request` method, just in case:

```
def send_request(request: Request, url: str) -> dict:
    headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    return data
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's an indentation just in your paste for your decorator? (since the `return` statements would be associated on the wrong level otherwise) .. but would it make sense to use the built-in support for handling custom exceptions in FastAPI instead of creating a decorator to do this? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers

Comment: @MatsLindh I fixed the indentation in my question. Thanks for that. Actually in my decorator I'm going to handle different errors and not just one. So I don't think having custom exception handlers would helm me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem just by unpacking the function in decorator into a non-coroutine object using `await` before returning it:

```
def handle_request(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = await func(*args, **kwargs)  # <- Added await here
        except (requests.exceptions.SSLError, requests.exceptions.RequestException) as ex:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=str(ex))

        return response

    return wrapper
```

Now everything is working fine.